Plot boxplot with mean and standard deviation by group in data frame in R
I want to plot mean and standard deviation bar by two levels of a factor. I found the solution on Plot mean and standard deviation by category.
According to the previous solution, I just get lineplot. However, I would like to get boxplot rather than lineplot. How could I get boxplots with sd bars?

To clarify the question. Would you like a boxplot with outliers, min, max, q1, q3 and median on top of which the mean and standard deviation would be indicated?

Box plots do not display means and standard deviations. Read ?boxplot

set.seed(101)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- gl(2, 50)

boxplot(y~x, las=1)
means <- by(y, x, mean); means
sds <- by(y, x, sd); sds
arrows(x0=c(1,2), y0=means-sds, y1=means+sds, col="blue", angle=90, length=0.1, code = 3, lwd=2)
points(means, pch=21, bg="red", col="blue", cex=2)



nice ~circumference with arrow() +1
